# React. What is the wrong with my ternar operator in className?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So, I have a simple tag `span` with `classNames` that trigger on a special condition, but for some reason my `class` in the `DOM` does not appear. I got just `class` word without anything like `<span class>...</span>`.

My span tag:

```
      <span key={total} className={'total' + ' ' + total === 0 ? 'total--empty' : ' '}>
        {total ? total : 0}
      </span>
```

Comment: Do you mean `('total' + ' ' + total) === 0 ? 'total--empty' : ' '` or `'total' + ' ' + (total === 0 ? 'total--empty' : ' ')` ...?

Comment: I mean on output - `<span class="total total--empty">` @MátéSafranka

Comment: I understand that. What I'm trying to get at is that JS probably evaluates `'total' + ' ' + total` and then compares the result to `0`, which is not what you want. Hence try parenthesizing your expression to enforce the order of evaluation.

Comment: @MátéSafranka - That's an answer, not a comment. :-)

Comment: Just a side-note, avoid breaking strings if not required. `'total' + ' '` could simply be written as `'total ' +`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is parsed like a ternary* : `(statement) ? whenTrue : whenFalse;`

```
// Which, translated to your code makes:
{ ('total' + ' ' + total === 0) ? 'total--empty' : ' '}
```

A string is truthy, thus 'total--empty'. What you need:

```
{ 'total' + ' ' + (total === 0 ? 'total--empty' : ' ')}
```

---

* Most people call it the ternary operator, but it is actually called the conditional operator. It's *a* ternary operator (an operator accepting three operands), and currently JavaScript's only ternary operator, but that could change.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably know about concept of [Operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence).

In your case, you are using '+' operator (precedence of 13) and comparison '===' operator (precedence of 10).

Therefore, the expression:

```
{'total' + ' ' + total === 0 ? 'total--empty' : ' '}
```

...will always return falsy value i.e. space.

Lets say total value is 0, so your expression executes as `'total'+' '+0` which becomes a string "total 0" NOT EQUAL TO 0.

What you need to do is Grouping of expression using '()' round brackets (precedence of 20).
i.e.

```
{'total' + ' ' + (total === 0 ? 'total--empty' : ' ')}
```

which has possible truthy/falsy outcome i.e. "total " or "total total--empty"

Answer (score 0):

You can try this below. We can make it with the help of curly braces and parenthesis.

Curly braces { } are special syntax in JSX. It is used to evaluate a JavaScript expression during compilation. A JavaScript expression can be a variable, function, an object, or any code that resolves into a value.

Parenthesis ( ) can be used to return something.
 [Curly braces versus parenthesis in ReactJS](https://medium.com/@leannezhang/curly-braces-versus-parenthesis-in-reactjs-4d3ffd33128f)

```
<span className={"total "+(total !== 0 ? "total_empty": null )} />
{total ? total : 0}
</span>
```

Comment: Hi Jeeva, welcome on SO. We often recommend not to post an answer which is already given. In this case, I've already posted the same solution as you have :) Also, we love explanations *why* you did what you did, so that a visitor can apply a solution somewhere else to :)

Comment: @Martijn - Actually, the above is different from yours. Yours works. The above is a syntax error.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but I recommend to delete your anwer (not sure if your rep. can do that). It'll reset your reputation as if this answer was never placed :)

Comment: @Martijn - Yes, users can always delete their answers if they're not accepted.

Comment: Oh, haha and that. Comments still apply for the most part though :) @jeeva, dont take this personally, So takes a bit getting used to.